# Synchronous spring webflux call retaining the order of operation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I have a simple use case and not sure how to do, as I'm new to spring webflux.

I'm using `spring boot webflux starters`.
I need to call 2 endpoints. Lets say `Endpoint1` and `Endpoint2`.

Whenever `Endpoint1` is hit with a request, I should hit the `Endpoint2` first with the same request and use the response from the `Endpoint2` to enrich the original request and then do something further.
`Endpoint1`'s request object needs to be enriched using the response from the `Endpoint2` before doing anything. How do I enforce this order using Spring webflux? In my case, the original request object is not enriched before it could be used further. Any help on this greatly appreciated!!!

FYI - call to `Endpoint2` is done using `webclient`

## Just a pseudo code:

```
public Mono<Response1> endpoint1(Request1 request1){

  Flux<Response2> reponse2 = webclient.getEndpoint2(request1); // Returns a Flux

  //use the above reponse2 to enrich the request1

  return webclient.getSomething(request1); //Returns Mono<Response1>

}
```

## Actual code:

```
 public Mono<ApplicationResponse> save(ApplicationRequest request) {

        return Mono.subscriberContext().flatMap(ctx -> {

            Mono blockingWrapper =  Mono.fromCallable(() ->
                    service.getId(request)
                            .subscriberContext(ctx)
                            .subscribe(id -> request.setId(id))
            ).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());

            return blockingWrapper.flatMap(o -> authService.getAccessToken()
                    .flatMap(token -> post("/save", request,
                            token.getAccessToken(),
                            ctx)
                            .bodyToMono(ApplicationResponse.class))
                    .log());
        });
    }
```

Comment: You should use transformation functions in this case. However, I can't see how you can use response2 response in this case as it is a Flux.

Take an example: Request2 returns a Flux: 1 -- 3 -- 7 -- End. How can you use them for request1?

Comment: The field in the request that needs to be enriched is a list. So the flux response2 should be used to populate that list. Please let me know if that’s not possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that you will have a Flux with getEndpoint2(request1), in this case, you can use collectList():

```java
return webclient.getEndpoint2(request1) // Flux<Response2>
         .collectList() // Mono<List<Response2>>
         .flatMap(list -> {
            // ... should handle empty list if needed
            finalRequest = createRequest(request1, list);
            return webclient.getSomething(finalRequest); // Mono<Response1>
         });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @htn. It was really helpful!!!
I see something interesting happening. It works as expected if I orchestrate all this from the Controller class, whereas if I call a service from my Controller class which orchestrates this flow, it doesn't seem to work as expected. Just wondering what am I missing? or is this how it is meant to be done?  I will add both working and non-working code to the answer section for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

I see something interesting happening. It works as expected if I orchestrate this from the Controller class, whereas if I call a service from my Controller class which orchestrates this flow, it doesn't seem to work as expected. Just wondering what am I missing? or is this how it is meant to be working?

This is the working code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/applications")
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationController {

    private final ApplicationService applicationService;
    private final ApplicationRequestMapper requestMapper;
    private final FeesService feesService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/save")
    public Mono<Application> saveApplication(@RequestBody ApplicationRequest request) {

        ApplicationRequest applicationRequest = requestMapper.apply(request);

        return Mono.subscriberContext()
                .flatMap(context -> feesService.calculateApplicationFees(applicationRequest)
                        .collectList())
                .map(feeItems -> applicationRequest.getFeeItems().addAll(feeItems))
                .flatMap(isRequestEnriched -> applicationService.saveApplication(applicationRequest)
                        .map(saveApplicationResponse -> {
                            Application application = new Application();
                            application.setLicenceId(saveApplicationResponse.getResponse().getLicenceNumber());
                            return application;
                        }))
                .onErrorMap(throwable -> new ApplicationException(String.format(SAVE_ERROR_MESSAGE,
                        request.getLicenceId()),
                        throwable, true, false))
                .log();
    }
}


@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationService extends ClientService{

     private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;  

         public Mono<SaveApplicationResponse> saveApplication(ApplicationRequest request) {

            return Mono.subscriberContext()
                .flatMap(context -> authenticationService.getAccessToken()
                        .flatMap(token -> post("/save",
                                request,
                                token.getAccessToken(),
                                context)
                                .bodyToMono(SaveApplicationResponse.class))
                        .log());
    }
}



@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FeesService extends ClientService{

     private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;  

        public Flux<FeeItem> calculateApplicationFees(ApplicationRequest request) {

        return Mono.subscriberContext()
                .flatMap(ctx -> authenticationService.getAccessToken()
                        .flatMap(token -> get("/fees", request, token.getAccessToken(), ctx)
                                .bodyToMono(FeeResponse.class))
                        .log())
                .flatMapMany(rsp -> Flux.fromIterable(rsp.getFeeItems()));
    }
}
```

Doesn't work if I do this.. Meaning, the request is never enriched at all:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/applications")
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationController {

    private final ApplicationService applicationService;
    private final ApplicationRequestMapper requestMapper;

     @PostMapping(value = "/save")
        public Mono<Application> saveApplication(@RequestBody ApplicationRequest request) {
            return Mono.subscriberContext()
                    .flatMap(context -> applicationService.saveApplication(requestMapper.apply(request))
                            .map(saveApplicationResponse -> {
                                Application application = new Application();
                                application.setLicenceId(saveApplicationResponse.getResponse().getLicenceNumber());
                                return application;
                            }))
                    .onErrorMap(throwable -> new ApplicationException(String.format(SAVE_ERROR_MESSAGE,
                            request.getLicenceId()),
                            throwable, true, false))
                    .log();
        }

}

@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationService extends ClientService{

     private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;
     private final FeesService feesService;


         public Mono<SaveApplicationResponse> saveApplication(ApplicationRequest request) {

            return Mono.subscriberContext()
                    .flatMap(context -> feesService.calculateApplicationFees(request)
                            .collectList())
                    .map(feeItems -> request.getFeeItems().addAll(feeItems))
                    .subscriberContext()
                    .flatMap(context -> authenticationService.getAccessToken()
                            .flatMap(token -> post("/save",
                                    request,
                                    token.getAccessToken(),
                                    context)
                                    .bodyToMono(SaveApplicationResponse.class))
                            .log());
        }
}



@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FeesService extends ClientService{

     private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;  

        public Flux<FeeItem> calculateApplicationFees(ApplicationRequest request) {

        return Mono.subscriberContext()
                .flatMap(ctx -> authenticationService.getAccessToken()
                        .flatMap(token -> get("/fees", request, token.getAccessToken(), ctx)
                                .bodyToMono(FeeResponse.class))
                        .log())
                .flatMapMany(rsp -> Flux.fromIterable(rsp.getFeeItems()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem comes from the second `.subscriberContext()`. It is a static method which creates a new `Mono`, that means the code before it never executes, that why `request` object does not change.

Anyway, your code is messy. Make it simpler. As far as I read your code, you do not need `Flux` at all. `feesService.calculateApplicationFees(...)`  should return `Mono<List<FeeItem>>`. There are too many unecessary `.log()` or `Mono.subscriberContext()`. Do you even need the context here?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @htn. Thanks for bringing up the problems in the code. I  sort of thinking about setting some attributes in the context so that those attributes could be cascaded to all the calls, and that's the reason for having those context out there. Just wondering is there any alternate way to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the second `.subscriberContext()`. It is a static method which creates a new `Mono`, that means the code before it never executes, that why `request` object does not change.

Anyway, your code is messy. Make it simpler. As far as I read your code, you do not need `Flux` at all. `feesService.calculateApplicationFees(...)`  should return `Mono<List<FeeItem>>`. There are too many unecessary `.log()` or `Mono.subscriberContext()`. Do you even need the context here?